# Discord.js add custom role to a mentioned user

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have a problem adding a custom role to a user. The command should look like this: `${prefix}addrole @user <role name>`. The user should receive a custom role and the bot should send a confirmation message. This is my code:

```js
client.on('message', (message) => {
  if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}addrole`)) {
    module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
      if (!message.member.hasPermissions('MANAGE_MEMBERS'))
        return message.reply("You don't have acces!");
      const rMember =
        message.guild.member(message.mentions.user.first()) ||
        message.guild.members.get(args[0]);
      if (!rMember) return message.reply("I couldn't find that user!");
      const role = args.join(' ').slice(22);
      if (!role) return message.reply('Please type a role!');
      const gRole = message.guild.roles.find(`name`, role);
      if (!gRole) return message.reply("I couldn't find that role!");

      if (nMember.roles.has(gRole.id));
      await nMember.addRole(gRole.id);

      try {
        nMember.send(`You received ${gRole.name}`);
      } catch (e) {
        message.channel.send(
          `The user <@${rMember.id}>, received the role ${gRole.name}. We tried to dm him but he disabled them.`
        );
      }
    };
    module.exports.help = {
      name: 'addrole',
    };
  }
});
```

Comment: hi could you be more specific... what problem did you encounter?

Answer (score 1):

The first problem I found comes from these two lines:

```js
if(nMember.roles.has(gRole.id));
    await(nMember.addRole(gRole.id));
```

---

#### First of all:

`await` is not a function, and thus you don't need parentheses. If you do put parentheses, you will get an error. Instead, just use:

```js
await nMember.addRole(gRole.id)
```

---

#### Second of all:

`GuildMember.roles.has` is deprecated. `discord.js` v12+ uses `Managers`, so you will have to add the cache property. Write:

```js
if (nMember.roles.cache.has(gRole.id))
```

This also applies to a line further up in the code:

```js
let gRole=message.guild.roles.find(`name`, role);
```

Replace that with

```js
let gRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name = role)
```

---

#### Third of all:

This issue is *also* seen in the second line of code I quoted:

```js
await nMember.addRole(gRole.id)
```

`addRole()` is also deprecated, instead use:

```js
await nMember.roles.cache.add(gRole.id)
```

---

#### Fourth of all, and I barely caught this:

`MANAGE_MEMBERS` is no longer a permission flag. Instead, use `MANAGE_ROLES`.

---

Overall the code could be cleaned up a bit, but I think that's all the errors I found.

Comment: Thanks for helping! The thing is it dosn't work. I don't have any errors, it won't work for some reason. I typed the role correctly and the prefix is right.

Comment: Add a `console.log()` line right where the command starts so that you know it's actually triggering correctly